# Simple template routes with plugins

Tags: plugin-development, routes

I'm attempting to create a simple route that points to a template from a plugin. Note that I am attempting to create a page on the front-facing website, **not** the admin panel. Plugin (named: 'curious') is created with the following method:

**craft/plugins/curious/CuriousPlugin.php**

```
class CuriousPlugin extends BasePlugin
{

    ...

    public function registerSiteRoutes()
    {
        return array(
            'example' => 'curious/templates/example'
        );
    }
}
```

I created a template in `craft/plugins/curious/templates/example.html`, however, going to the URL `/example` just gives me a 404. If I visit `/admin/curious/example` it does exist and works. However, I don't want the page to be in the admin, I would like it to be visible on the front-facing website.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This might be obvious, but is your plugin installed and activated?

Comment: It is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky topic for a simple answer. Off the top of my head, there are two general approaches you may fall in for this. I'll keep my answer fairly broad:

### URL-Enabled Elements

You can create an Element Type and implement the method [routeRequestForMatchedElement](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/BaseElementType#routeRequestForMatchedElement-detail). This approach would require you to have a Custom Element, and have a need for that Element to be URL-enabled like Entries or Categories or Products.

For this approach you would not need to setup `registerSiteRoutes` .The Element API would handle the front-end request in the same way other URL-enabled Element requests are handled.

### Your Plugin has a template in the plugins template folder that you want to render on the front-end of the website

The main concept to understand here is that Craft has two Template Modes: `Site` and `CP`. Depending on which template mode is active, Craft will look in different places for the template to load.

To set the template mode in your code, you can use the following:

```
// Tell craft to look in the front end craft/templates folder for a template
craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::Site);

// Tell craft to look in the back end craft/app/templates folder for a template (where you can later update the path to target your plugin template folder)
craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::CP);
```

Once you are on the right side of the fence, you can then render the template you want and return it to the page. You would do this in one of two places:

**Controllers** If your logic is taking place in a controller you will need to render the template and return the rendered template to the page as a variable. Two scenarios in controllers where this may occur:

Responding to a page with errors:

```
$output = craft()->curiousService->getTemplate()

craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
  'stuff' => $output
));
```

Rendering a template as the final step in the controller action (this may apply to CP scenarios more than front-end scenarios).

```
$this->renderTemplate('curious/example', array(
    'stuff' => $stuff,
));
```

**Variables** If your logic is taking place in the middle of the page, you may need to create a custom variable that renders your template and outputs it when the variable is called:

```
{{ craft.myCuriousPlugin.getMyTemplate() }}
```

---

### Be sure to Flip/Flop

In either case, since you are flip/flopping on which part of the site is rendering your templates, you'll want to be sure to set your Template Mode back to the `Site` side of things once you are done:

```
// Front end page calls your plugin

// Switch things to look for templates on the back end
craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::CP);

// Do your thing
//
// Note the template path is just the name of the plugin 
// and the folder in the plugins template folder that you 
// want to access, and that we are omitting the word 'templates'
$html = craft()->templates->render('curious/example', array(
  'someVariable'      => $yourResults,
  'someOtherVariable' => $someOtherStuff
));

// Switch things back to look for templates on the front-end
// so that any template-related things that after you behave
// as normal
craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::Site);
```

Comment: The controller method still has two issues. 1) It creates a route on the front-end and admin. 2) The template is found and able to be rendered on the admin `/admin/curious/example` but on the frontend the template is not able to be found. This really isn't the appropriate approach to solve this issue.

Comment: What action is happening when you need to render the template? Is it a form submission or just a variable on a page?